# Save Stdout to variable when using StdoutPipe

Tags: go

I am trying to use Go to run commands that contain a pipe, and then save the output of the command to a variable to be used later. The code below will retrieve the file name of the latest file to be uploaded to Amazon S3 and output it to the terminal. The point of this is so that the file name can be used later to generate the item.Key:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c1 := exec.Command("aws", "s3", "ls", "bucket", "--recursive")
    c2 := exec.Command("sort")
    c3 := exec.Command("tail", "-n", "1")
    c4 := exec.Command("awk", "{print $4}")
    c2.Stdin, _ = c1.StdoutPipe()
    c3.Stdin, _ = c2.StdoutPipe()
    c4.Stdin, _ = c3.StdoutPipe()
    c4.Stdout = os.Stdout
    _ = c4.Start()
    _ = c3.Start()
    _ = c2.Start()
    _ = c1.Run()
    _ = c2.Wait()
    _ = c3.Wait()
    _ = c4.Wait()
}
```

Instead of/as well as outputting the file name to the terminal I would like to save the output to a variable.

Would anyone know where to start with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign any `io.Writer` to a `Stdout`. So if you want to get the output stored into a variable, the easiest way might be:

```
out := &bytes.Buffer{}
c4.Stdout = out
```

Then the output is stored in out, which can be get by calling `out.Bytes()` or `out.String()` depending on you want a `[]byte` or a `string`.

To also have the output streamed to the screen, `io.MultiWriter` can help. It writes to all given writer when a write is called. So you can do this:

```
out := &bytes.Buffer{}
c4.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(out, os.Stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
When trying to implement the bytes.Buffer I get the following error: 
`cannot use &out (type **bytes.Buffer) as type io.Writer in assignment: **bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)`
Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: @CJW I typoed. There was an `&` before the `out`, which should not be there.